# I run the kserve example for sklearn-iris and got `302 Found`

Tags: kubeflow, kubeflow-kserve

**serving exam model**

1. create `namespace`

   ```
   $ kubectl create namespace kserve-test
   ```
2. create `InferenceService`

   ```
   $ kubectl apply -n kserve-test -f - <<EOF
   apiVersion: "serving.kserve.io/v1beta1"
   kind: "InferenceService"
   metadata:
     name: "sklearn-iris"
   spec:
     predictor:
       model:
         modelFormat:
           name: sklearn
         storageUri: "gs://kfserving-examples/models/sklearn/1.0/model"
   EOF
   ```

   check

   ```
   $ kubectl get inferenceservices sklearn-iris -n kserve-test
   ```

   ```
   NAME           URL                                           READY   PREV   LATEST   PREVROLLEDOUTREVISION   LATESTREADYREVISION                    AGE
   sklearn-iris   http://sklearn-iris.kserve-test.example.com   True           100                              sklearn-iris-predictor-default-00001   5h11m
   ```
3. check `SERVICE_HOSTNAME`, `INGRESS_PORT`, `INGRESS_HOST`

   - `SERVICE_HOSTNAME`

     ```
     $ SERVICE_HOSTNAME=$(kubectl get inferenceservice sklearn-iris -n kserve-test -o jsonpath='{.status.url}' | cut -d "/" -f 3)
     $ echo $SERVICE_HOSTNAME
     ```

     ```
     sklearn-iris.kserve-test.example.com
     ```
   - `INGRESS_PORT`

     ```
     $ INGRESS_PORT=$(kubectl -n istio-system get service istio-ingressgateway -o jsonpath='{.spec.ports[?(@.name=="http2")].nodePort}')
     $ echo $INGRESS_PORT
     ```

     ```
     31018
     ```
   - `INGRESS_HOST`

     ```
     $ INGRESS_HOST=192.168.219.100
     ```

     `192.168.219.100` : Internal IP of my device
4. create input

   ```
   $ cat <<EOF > "./iris-input.json"
   {
     "instances": [
       [6.8,  2.8,  4.8,  1.4],
       [6.0,  3.4,  4.5,  1.6]
     ]
   }
   EOF
   ```
5. send request

   ```
   $ curl -v -H "Host: ${SERVICE_HOSTNAME}" http://${INGRESS_HOST}:${INGRESS_PORT}/v1/models/sklearn-iris:predict -d @./iris-input.json
   ```

   ```
   *   Trying 192.168.219.100:31018...
   * Connected to 192.168.219.100 (192.168.219.100) port 31018 (#0)
   > POST /v1/models/sklearn-iris:predict HTTP/1.1
   > Host: sklearn-iris.kserve-test.example.com
   > User-Agent: curl/7.71.1
   > Accept: */*
   > Content-Length: 76
   > Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
   > 
   * upload completely sent off: 76 out of 76 bytes
   * Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
   < HTTP/1.1 302 Found
   < location: /dex/auth?client_id=kubeflow-oidc-authservice&redirect_uri=%2Flogin%2Foidc&response_type=code&scope=profile+email+groups+openid&state=MTY3MTU5MDMxOHxFd3dBRUhZek16WktlRlZJZFc1alowVlROVTA9fFynQ-3082qPF_-qUwnYllySrEQPAKGqpBuF-Pu9gcnx
   < date: Wed, 21 Dec 2022 02:38:38 GMT
   < x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 6
   < server: istio-envoy
   < content-length: 0
   < 
   * Connection #0 to host 192.168.219.100 left intact
   ```

   **Got `302 Found`.**

   **As far as I know, this result is because I was asked for authentication from Dex.**

#### what i did to solve this

1. **Authentication**

   I tried to get the authservice_session token by following the method here: [kserve:github](https://github.com/kserve/kserve/blob/master/docs/samples/istio-dex/README.md)

   1. From CLI

      ```
      $ CLUSTER_IP=$(kubectl -n istio-system get service istio-ingressgateway -o jsonpath='{.spec.clusterIP}')
      ```

      CLUSTER_IP: `10.103.239.220`

      ```
      $ curl -v http://${CLUSTER_IP}
      ```

      ```
      *   Trying 10.103.239.220:80...
      * Connected to 10.103.239.220 (10.103.239.220) port 80 (#0)
      > GET / HTTP/1.1
      > Host: 10.103.239.220
      > User-Agent: curl/7.71.1
      > Accept: */*
      > 
      * Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
      < HTTP/1.1 302 Found
      < content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
      < location: /dex/auth?client_id=kubeflow-oidc-authservice&redirect_uri=%2Flogin%2Foidc&response_type=code&scope=profile+email+groups+openid&state=MTY3MTU5MzE2MXxFd3dBRUdGM2JUSnlaMkZVYjFWUVNFa3dURGs9fEDuO8ql3cFsetSfKntLvFV0al5tEZJeh23VK-JrJubM
      < date: Wed, 21 Dec 2022 03:26:01 GMT
      < content-length: 269
      < x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 4
      < server: istio-envoy
      < 
      <a href="/dex/auth?client_id=kubeflow-oidc-authservice&amp;redirect_uri=%2Flogin%2Foidc&amp;response_type=code&amp;scope=profile+email+groups+openid&amp;state=MTY3MTU5MzE2MXxFd3dBRUdGM2JUSnlaMkZVYjFWUVNFa3dURGs9fEDuO8ql3cFsetSfKntLvFV0al5tEZJeh23VK-JrJubM">Found</a>.

      * Connection #0 to host 10.103.239.220 left intact
      ```

      I stuck at this stage. I think it's wrong to see `302 Found`.
   2. From the browser

      Copy the token content from the cookie `authservice_session`

      ```
      $ SESSION =MTY3MTUyODQ2M3xOd3dBTkRkRVExbEdVa0kzVFRJMFMwOU9VRE5hV2pSS1VGVkNSRVJVUlRKVlVVOUlTa2hDVWpOU1RUZFRVRkJGVTFGV1N6UktXVkU9fCoQdbMu_diLBJAKLZSmF4qoqQTlINKq7A63hy-QNQcR
      ```

      ```
      $ curl -v -H "Host: ${SERVICE_HOSTNAME}" -H "Cookie: authservice_session=${SESSION}"  http://${INGRESS_HOST}:${INGRESS_PORT}/v1/models/sklearn-iris:predict -d ./iris-input.json
      ```

      got `404 Not Found`

      ```
      curl -v -H "Host: ${SERVICE_HOSTNAME}" -H "Cookie: authservice_session=${SESSION}"  http://${CLUSTER_IP}/v1/models/${MODEL_NAME}:predict -d @./iris-input.json
      ```

      got `404 Not Found`
2. **added Envoy filter for bypass Dex**

   ```
   $ vi envoyfilter.yaml
   ```

   ```
   apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
   kind: EnvoyFilter
   metadata:
     name: sklearn-iris-filter
     namespace: istio-system
   spec:
     workloadSelector:
       labels:
         istio: ingressgateway
     configPatches:
     - applyTo: VIRTUAL_HOST
       match:
         routeConfiguration:
           vhost:
             name: sklearn-iris.kserve-test.example.com:31018
       patch:
           operation: MERGE
           value:
             per_filter_config:
               envoy.ext_authz:
                 disabled: true
   ```

   ```
   $ kubectl apply -f envoyfilter.yaml
   ```

   **Note**: spec.configPatches.match.routeConfiguration.vhost.name :  `sklearn-iris.kserve-test.example.com:31018`

   It's not working.

   Got still `302 Found`
3. **External Authorization**

   reference: https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/issues/4549#issuecomment-932259673

   add AuthorizationPolicy

   ```
   $ vi authorizationpolicy.yaml
   ```

   ```
   apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
   kind: AuthorizationPolicy
   metadata:
     name: dex-auth
     namespace: istio-system
   spec:
     selector:
       matchLabels:
         istio: ingressgateway
     action: CUSTOM
     provider:
       # The provider name must match the extension provider defined in the mesh config.
       name: dex-auth-provider
     rules:
     # The rules specify when to trigger the external authorizer.
       - to:
         - operation:
             notPaths: ["/v1*"]
   ```

   ```
   $ kubectl apply -f authorizationpolicy.yaml
   ```

   **Note**: rules.to.operation: `notPaths: ["/v1*"]`

   and delete envoyfilters named `authn-filter` that originally existed

   ```
   $ kubectl delete -n istio-system envoyfilters.networking.istio.io authn-filter
   ```

   next, restart `deployment/istiod`

   ```
   $ kubectl rollout restart deployment/istiod -n istio-system
   ```

   It's not working.

   Got still `302 Found` if don't delete envoyfilters named `authn-filter` that originally existed, or block the connection if I delete `authn-filter` .

**What I need help**:

- How can I get Dex authorization and make a connected?
- Or how can I bypass Dex if I can't get Dex authorization?
- Maybe my model serving example is wrong. Thanks for any advice on what's wrong.

**env**:

- ubuntu 20.04
- ```
  $ kubectl version --client && kubeadm version
  ```

  ```
  Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.13", GitCommit:"a43c0904d0de10f92aa3956c74489c45e6453d6e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-08-17T18:28:56Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
  kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.13", GitCommit:
  ```
- I installed `istio` and `kanative` that included in the `kubeflow` manifest by following: [kubeflow/manifasts](https://github.com/kubeflow/manifests).

  ```
  $ kubectl get pod -n istio-system
  istio-system                authservice-0                                            1/1     Running
  istio-system                cluster-local-gateway-5449f87d9b-bb4vs                   1/1     Running
  istio-system                istio-ingressgateway-77b9d69b74-xmv98                    1/1     Running
  istio-system                istiod-67fcb675b5-kzfvd                                  1/1     Running
  ```

  ```
  $ kubectl get pod -n knative-eventing  
  $ kubectl get pod -n knative-serving
  knative-eventing            eventing-controller-8457bd9747-855lc                     1/1     Running
  knative-eventing            eventing-webhook-69986cfb5d-hn7tx                        1/1     Running
  knative-serving             activator-7c5cd78566-pz6ns                               2/2     Running
  knative-serving             autoscaler-98487645d-vh5wk                               2/2     Running
  knative-serving             controller-7546f544b7-mng9g                              2/2     Running
  knative-serving             domain-mapping-5d56bfc7d-5cb9l                           2/2     Running
  knative-serving             domainmapping-webhook-696559d49c-p8rwr                   2/2     Running
  knative-serving             net-istio-controller-c4d469c-lt5fl                       2/2     Running 
  knative-serving             net-istio-webhook-855bcb6747-wbl4x                       2/2     Running
  knative-serving             webhook-59f9fdd446-xsf6n                                 2/2     Running
  ```
- And installed `KServe` and `KServe Built-in ClusterServingRuntimes` by following: [kserve installation](https://kserve.github.io/website/0.9/admin/serverless/#5-install-kserve-built-in-clusterservingruntimes)

  ```
  $ kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kserve/kserve/releases/download/v0.9.0/kserve.yaml
  $ kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kserve/kserve/releases/download/v0.9.0/kserve-runtimes.yaml
  ```

  ```
  $ kubectl get pod -n kserve
  kserve-controller-manager-5fc887875d-m7rlp   2/2     Running
  ```
- **check `gateway` selector**

  - `knative-local-gateway` in namespace `knative-serving`

    ```
    $ kubectl get gateways knative-local-gateway -n knative-serving -o yaml
    ```

    ```
    spec:
      selector:
        app: cluster-local-gateway
        istio: cluster-local-gateway
    ```
  - `istio-ingressgateway` in namespace `istio-system`

    ```
    $ kubectl get gateways istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system -o yaml
    ```

    ```
    spec:
      selector:
        app: istio-ingressgateway
        istio: ingressgateway
    ```
  - `cluster-local-gateway` in namespace `istio-system`

    ```
    $ kubectl get gateways cluster-local-gateway -n istio-system -o yaml
    ```

    ```
    spec:
      selector:
        app: cluster-local-gateway
        istio: cluster-local-gateway
    ```
  - `kubeflow-gateway` in namespace `kubeflow`

    ```
    $ kubectl get gateways kubeflow-gateway -n kubeflow -o yaml
    ```

    ```
    spec:
      selector:
        istio: ingressgateway
    ```

Answer (score 1):

I met the same issue, please try to specify the session by --cookie instead of apply it in the headers.

```
curl --cookie "authservice_session=${SESSION}" -v -H "Host: ${SERVICE_HOST}" "http://${INGRESS_HOST}:${INGRESS_PORT}/v1/models/sklearn-iris:predict" -d @./iris-input.json
```